# highcharts x-axis not showing with series of just one value

Tags: highcharts

I use highcharts for a chart. I made series with "linkedTo" because I need to group the columns by region and generate a legend displaying these regions. Until then, the result is the desired one. But I can not display the name of my categories on the X axis. Under each column there should be "A", "B", ... As in the picture. See the jsfiddle for the code. Thank you for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/yucca/hpkLy6t0/24/

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'TEST'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'TEST'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
},

legend: {
    enabled: true,
    labelFormatter: function() {
                                return  this.userOptions.id
                            }
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
        }
    }
},

tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
},

series: [
    {
    id:'China',
    color: '#004f9e',
    data: [1100]
     },
     {
     id:'International',
     color: '#e73357',
      data: [10]
     },
     {
     linkedTo: 'International',
     color: '#e73357',
     data: [1000]
     },
     {
     linkedTo: 'China',
     color: '#004f9e',
      data: [686]
      }
    ]
});
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PwO6.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a slight alteration to your `series` in order for this to work.

```
series: [{
        data: [{
            id:'China',
            color: '#004f9e',
            y: 1100
         },{
            id:'International',
            color: '#e73357',
            y: 10
         },{
            linkedTo: 'International',
            color: '#e73357',
             y: 1000
         },{
         linkedTo: 'China',
         color: '#004f9e',
          y: 686
          }], 
       }]
```

What I did is the following:

- I changed the `data[]` so it holds an array of your values.
- I changed the values stored as `data: [686]` to `y: 686`

[Here you can find a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpkLy6t0/35/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. By cons, with your solution the legend is not as I would like. I found this solution, meanwhile, using grouping: false on the plotOptions of the series > http://jsfiddle.net/yucca/jb33sza0/4/ Thanks again. Have a nice day

Comment: @user3951700 Ah, that solution is much easier. I had been looking for that one too but couldn't find it. Happy you got it to work!